# How to enable anonymous branding site

Tags: sharepoint-2016

I use visual studio to deploy custom master page and I create publishing site that inherit this mater page. Then I enable anonymous the publishing site but it is till ask user and password when I go on. Please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you published the site on an existing web appliance where other site need authentication?

If you have, create a new new appliance and set appliance to anonymous and disable any other authentication methods.]